# Proof of Liouville's theorem and the construction of transcendental numbers - Hardy et al.

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, transcendental-numbers, algebraic-numbers, liouville-numbers

I've been trying to understand the proof of Liouville's theorem given in "Intro to Theory of Numbers"- G.H. Hardy et al. and not able to understand few steps. The proof snippet is attached.
[image]

Can someone please help me understand the following
a) How does the author conclude "there is a number $M(\epsilon)$ such that $|f^\prime(x)|< M \quad \epsilon -1 < x < \epsilon$"?

b) In the last line of the proof, he says that $\epsilon$ is not approximable to any order higher than n. But $p/q$ is an approximation of $\epsilon$. So with larger values of $n$, the lower bound should not hold. Maybe I'm not able to understand the conclusion this theorem wanted to prove in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The function $f'$ is a polynomial function and therefore its restriction to any bounded interval is bounded. So, take $M>\sup_{x\in[\xi-1,\xi+1]}\bigl|f'(x)\bigr|$ and then $\xi-1<x<\xi+1\implies\bigl|f'(x)\bigr|<M$.

b) The goal is precisely to get a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.